# call controller from model ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to ember and How can I call controller from model.

structure

```
ember
-source
--controllers
---controller1(method1)
--models
---model1 --(Call controller1.method1)
--routes
--views
--router.js
--appname-app.js
```

I tried these ways

```
var subs= AppName.controller1.method1();



var cd = Soni.controller1.create(); 
var subs = cd.method1();



var controller = $(this).get('controllers.controller1');
var subs = controller.method1();
```

**Error:** ember.min.js:205 Uncaught TypeError: AppName.controller1.method1() is not a function

Where exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: this doesn't make any sense, I don't think this is posible. Model is are objects..... What is your point on doing this, please be more specific on what is that you want o accomplish to a higher level..

Comment: You need to state the reason you think you need to do that. That is not just an anti-pattern for Ember...it's simply the wrong way to do whatever you're trying to do. I can't think of any reason why a model instance would need to reach out to a particular controller. There probably is a perfectly elegant way to do what you're trying to do, just need to know what that thing is :)

Comment: You can´t controller values can be accessed in your template {{valueincontroller}}, route controllerFor('route').get('value') or other controller via injection. Model just holds data.